# Lazy-loaded overriden or custom CMS Components

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I was trying to test Lazy-loaded CMS components on ongoing Spartacus project with version **2.1.4** and I wasn't able to properly display the components. Before I continue with further investigation, I just want to check couple of things:

- is it possible to lazy-load components which we have overriden, for example BannerComponent, SearchBoxComponent...?
- is it possible to apply lazy-load on custom CMS components ?
- are there any limitations when this feature won't work? Maybe in combination with some other feature?

There are many OOTB Spartacus CMS components that we have overriden in our project, and I have defined lazy-load feature for couple of them like it is described here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/#lazy-loaded-cms-components-code-splitting inside modules for certain components, this is one example:
[breadcrumb.module.ts example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz1zv.png)
and after the build, chunks are there, visible from source tab also, but components aren't displayed and there are errors because of missing modules (such as CommonModule, RouterModule, basically for everything that we used in our custom implementation..) which are declared in corresponding module but for some reason aren't registered at all.

Any guesses what we should fix in order to check if this feature is working in our architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to stick "CMS-driven lazy loading of feature modules" (as explained here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/lazy-loading-guide/) instead of lazy loading of separate components (using `component: () => import()`) as it's simpler to make it work.

The idea is to define CMS mapping inside the module, which then will be lazy loaded (with components, services, etc.) instead of lazy loading separate (and decoupled) components. Then, in the root application, we let Spartacus know, which feature module should be loaded, when we want to render specified component (example: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/lazy-loading-guide/#configuration-of-lazy-loaded-modules)

Using `component: () => import()` will lazy load only component code (no module, unless defined in the same file), such a component will have access to global (root) services, etc. It's still useful in some cases, but a bit problematic to make it work in more than basic scenarios (but this will improve in Spartacus 3.x/4.0).

Regarding your questions:

- is it possible to lazy-load components which we have overriden, for example BannerComponent, SearchBoxComponent...?

Yes. Briefly explained here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/lazy-loading-guide/#wrapping-library-code-in-a-lazy-loaded-module

- is it possible to apply lazy-load on custom CMS components ?

Yes.

- are there any limitations when this feature won't work? Maybe in combination with some other feature?

As explained above.

Comment: Thanks @dungan. I have tried it on several modules, works fine. It's even better since many components can be defined inside one module configuration. So it is working for custom components, but when I try out lazy loading of modules where OOTB components are overriden, I get the generated chunk for it with mapping for our custom component but still the OOTB component is displayed on the storefront. Do you know what could be the issue? Example https://imgur.com/a/DEgLMDw

Comment: Used wrong tag in the comment above @dunqan. Also to add, I have tried to lazy load module separatelly and within some another module, the result is the same - OOTB Spartacus components AccountAddressBookComponent and ResetPasswordComponent are displayed insted overriden ones. Config is in app.module.ts like it is on this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/PkTyijc FYI still on spartacus 2.1.4 version